# Not allowing Android app to be installed on WiFi-only devices

Tags: android, android-market-filtering, uses-feature

I have an application that require the GSM/CDMA radio to be present and the ability to read the devices' IMEI (which is not present on WiFi-only devices).

How would I use the `<uses-feature>` to *restrict* my app from being visible to WiFi only devices on Play?

Right now I have this in my manifest:

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony.gsm"
    android:required="true" />
```

Should I also add `android.hardware.telephony.cdma` to allow the app to be installed on devices using GSM and CDMA as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use android.hardware.telephony instead.  Otherwise you require a specific type of telephony, which may not be available.  And if you required both CDMA and GSM you'd end up only working on a very small set of phones that have both.

Please note that CDMA doesn't have an IMEI, it has its own identifiers.